# What fields are exactly calculated in Third Round of Calculations?

Tags: cpq

New to Salesforce CPQ here.

I was going through the Salesforce documentation and read that in Third Round of Calculations, CPQ:

1. Calculates Fixed Items
2. Calculates Dynamic Items
3. Calculates Totals

Does anyone have an idea what is meant by Fixed and Dynamic Items and what all field values are considered under them? I did some googling around but was not able to find anything.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

> Subscription products have two pricing types, controlled by the Subscription Pricing field.
>
> • Fixed Price: This product gets its list price from a price book entry.
>
> • Percent of Total: This product’s list price is a percentage of the quote, quote line group, or a bundle’s total price

The fixed price items go in to the process first, so that the dynamic (%age) items can be calculated.

(from https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/final_cpq_map.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @Dave. And apologies for the late reply. This helps. Is there any Salesforce Documentation which mentions the exact OOTB fields which are part of Fixed and Dynamic items.

Comment: You'd need to look at the Subscription Pricing field on a product to know if that product is fixed or percentage. If it's fixed price, then that's a fixed item and if it's a percentage of total then that's a dynamic item.

It's the products that are fixed/dynamic, rather than individual fields.